# Trying to find R equivalent for SetConf from Java

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

In Java, you can do something like:

```
sc.setConf('spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString','true')
```

What would the equivalent be in R? I've looked at the methods available to the `sc` object, and can't find any obvious way of doing this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem.

We can do the following:

```
sql(sqlContext,'SET spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString=true')
```

This fixes everything.

Comment: Cool, I haven't thought about something like this.

Comment: NP, thats why I figured I should post it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set environment variables during `SparkContext` initialization. `sparkR.init` has a number of optional arguments including:

- `sparkEnvir` - a list of environment variables to set on worker nodes.
- `sparkExecutorEnv` - a list of environment variables to be used when launching executors

In your case something like this should do the trick:

```
sparkEnvir <- list('spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString'='true')
sc <- sparkR.init(master, app_name, sparkEnvir=sparkEnvir)
```

Comment: If this works I'm going to marry you possibly. Been bugged by this all day.

Comment: Hey. This isnt really working for me. I'm doing this: `$> sparkR` ... bunch of spam about things being loaded

`sparkR.stop()
sparkEnv<-list('spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString'='true')
sc<-sparkR.init(sparkEnvir=sparkEnv)
x<-parquetFile(sqlContext,'path/to/folder')

Invalid jobj 1. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.`

If I then try: `sparkRSQL.init()` it gives me the same error.

Please help - thanks!

Comment: It looks like generally issue with stopping and creating a new `sparkContext`.