# SparkR re-initialisation not working

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying to follow the answer provided here:

[Trying to find R equivalent for SetConf from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085937/trying-to-find-r-equivalent-for-setconf-from-java)

When I do that, I'm loading SparkR:

```
sparkR
....initialisation spam....
sparkR.stop()
sc<-sparkR.init(sparkEnvir=....)
sqlContext<-sparkRSQL.init(sc)
```

I get an error message:

```
Error in callJMethod(x,'getClass'):
  Invalid jobj 1. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
```

This same error message comes up when I do not use the `sparkEnvir` argument as well, so just standard stop and re-initialisation seems to be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have a DataFrame loaded from stopped Spark session. You need to reload the DataFrame after you init the Spark again.